# I get Uncaught TypeError: ite.create is not a function when i try to deploy a Vite reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, frontend, vite

I get Uncaught TypeError: ite.create is not a function when i try to deploy a Vite reactjs app.

because of this line of code in vite itself, I suppose `var as = ite.create();`